# Data don't automatically updated that I uploaded from django admin

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-admin

In development , I uploaded some data from django admin to a table. But when I refresh a page that uses that table then the new added data don't appears . It appears only when i rerun the manage.py runserver command. How can i fix this?

I am expecting that the new data from the table should appear after added through django-admin.

Comment: show me the code

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Very likely that is because you somehow "cache" a queryset, and thus the query only runs once. But without any view logic, it is hard to tell.

Comment: Solved the issue , I was using model.object.all() outside the view function (below the imports) , now I put it inside the view function and now it's working fine .